# ufw inactive, unable to connect to MySQL through port 3337

Tags: mysql, ufw

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database through port 3337, but it keeps failing.
I think it is not a MySQL problem because I'm able to connect using port 3306.

This is the command I'm using:

```
mysql --host=ensembldb.ensembl.org --port=3337 --user=anonymous
```

My ufw is inactive and I tried doing:

```
nc -zv ensembldb.ensembl.org 3306         
Connection to ensembldb.ensembl.org 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!

nc -zv ensembldb.ensembl.org 3337
Connection to ensembldb.ensembl.org 3337 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

I don't understand what can be the problem, any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: I have no problem connecting to that server on port 3337.

Comment: Indeed I think it's something related to my settings, but I don't know what. And this was working three weeks ago... I didn't change anything, I only did some software updates...